# Generate number from given range

Tags: code-golf, number, open-ended-function

Your function must accept three numbers in any order:

- A signed real number (or `±Infinity`) - The number (`N`) for which you have to generate a number from the range
- A signed integer - Minimum of the range
- A signed integer - Maximum of the range

**Input**:

- The minimum of the range will always be less than the maximum of the range, so don't worry about it
- `N` can be any real (if it is possible `Infinity` and `-Infinity` also can be passed)

**Requirements**:

- Your function must output same result each time for same inputs
- Your function must output different result each time for different `N` (except when it's due to a floating point error)
- The output must be in the given range
- The outputs of your function for all numbers `N` must cover the entire range (except when missing outputs are due to floating point error)

**Please specify**:

- The order of the input
- Is it possible to pass `±Infinity` as a `N`?
- Are the minimum and maximum of the range inclusive or exclusive?

Unable to provide test cases because there are many ways to solve this problem, so please provide your test cases.

The shortest code in each programming language wins!

Comment: You need to provide the random distribution that the wind speed follows, otherwise a simple lerp could solve it

Comment: @mousetail I don't know what is lerp, But if it is built in function in your language so there is no problem to use it. Also I don't need to provide the random distribution that the wind speed follows because it is just a story for challenge and the main task is to generating number from given range based on input number

Comment: You still need to specify the range of the input number to make any algorithm work

Comment: Windspeed is probably a log normal distribution, but you need to know the exact parameters so that you can prove your RNG is actually random

Comment: @mousetail The range is the range of `float` or `double` (it's up to you) which provides your language

Comment: @mousetail Don't give so much attention to the story about random please

Comment: Linear? That's already a big problem because floats or doubles have very different accuracies depending on the order of magnitude. This would make the second half of the number unusable

Comment: @mousetail You don't need to worry about floating point errors. If the answer will be same for different numbers because of floating point error than it is fine. I mentioned it in challenge

Comment: When a solution works fine for small values but eventually breaks due to numerical limits, you can say you just ignore them since it works in theory. However, for this challenge any answer is going to immediately run into the float limit and have big deviations for any test case.

Comment: @mousetail I mentioned `except when it's due to a floating point error` so there is no problem with this. Challenge doesn't require to give an algorithm which must work with any number. Of course there are a limits of numbers, but you can ignore them. The requirements are simple and doesn't require to bypass the limits

Comment: This question just seems to be "find a mapping between a value from (-inf, inf) to (a,b)?

Comment: @97.100.97.109  Yes, and we need straightforward note about it! _Or_ (-inf, inf), _or_ interval must be specified

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Not certainly in that way. It is easy to mapping `(-inf, inf)` to `(a,b)` because there is already a formula for this [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). The question is mapping `(-inf, inf)` to `[a,b)` or `[a,b]`

Comment: No, you said it was from min float to max float, not inf

Comment: You also said distribution was linear even though you can't linearly map to infinity

Comment: @mousetail I don't know the max of floating numbers for each programming language, so in general you can pass any number, but of course it will be limited by your language. Also I didn't say anything about `linerar`, you are free to use any other methods

Comment: @WheatWizard Can you please say what exactly is unclear? Because I don't what else I can add to clarify the challenge

Comment: Do -0 and +0 have to return different results?

Comment: Do answers get to decide if `±Infinity` are valid inputs, or is it dependent on whether the language allows them?

Comment: @CommandMaster 1. Interesting question, to be honest I don't know what should I answer, because in JavaScript we also have `-0` and `+0` but `-0 == +0`, so I guess that it depends on the respondent. 2. First of all it depends on language, secondly it depends on respondent. If passing `+-Infinity` helps him to wrote fewer code than why not?)

Comment: I'm still unclear on what exactly "You are not allowed to use a (pseudo or true) random number generator" means.  I also don't understand how a pseudo random number generator could even be helpful, since you need to ensure that there is no collision.

Comment: @WheatWizard I added it just to be sure that different values for different inputs are not depend on random. If it's confusing and/or it is obvious that you shouldn't use random numbers I can remove it

Comment: There doesn’t seem to be a requirement that the mapping is surjective. Is that intended?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg In theory the mapping function must be bijective but because of floating point errors and because of we don't have all numbers in computer in practice the mapping will be surjective

Comment: If you intend to require that, you should edit that into the question. It currently states no requirements about bijectivity or surjectivity, and there’s nothing to stop someone from (say) ignoring the max bound and mapping into (min, min + 1).

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Could you please help with editing my challenge? I'm not sure how to correctly add this information

Comment: You could simply add: “The outputs of your function for all numbers `N` must cover the entire range (except when missing outputs are due to floating point error).”

Comment: @AndersKaseorg Thank you very much! I added this to requirements

Answer (score 6):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 29 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c:a+(b-a)/(1+2**c)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhZ7cxJzk1ISFRJ1knSSrRK1NZJ0EzX1NQy1jbS0kjUham6aFxRl5pVopGnoGusYGugYaGpyoYoYYojoGgFVQbQvWAChAQ)

Does not include the upper bound.

Uses the mapping
$$f(c) = \frac{a-b}{1+2^c}+a$$

[An interactive graph of what this looks like:](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jme6s1vlej)

[image: graph of the above function]

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 33 bytes

```
N@Rescale[#1,{-∞,∞},{#2,#3}]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7388hKLU4OTEnNVrZUKda91HHPB0grtWpVjbSUTaujVX7H1CUmVfikBZtoKNraKBjaBDLBRMxNDDAFNQ1whQCmQoV/A8A)

Mathematica easily operates with infinities both signs, so here it is. For input infinite values you can use `\[Infinity]` or `∞` with sign.

Answer (score 3):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 10 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 8.21 bytes

```
-s2@1+/A$+
```

Port of [97.100.97.109's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258882/108687)

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhardIuNHAy19R1VtCECUPEFy3WNuQwNuAwgXAA)

```
-s2@1+/A$+ # stack is min, max, wind
-          # subtract
 s         # swap, wind is on top
  2@       # 2 ^ wind
    1+     # add one
      /    # divide (max-min) by (1 + 2^wind)
       A$+ # add the first input
```

### [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.93 bytes

```
-DZs*$
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLdF2iirVUIByo2IJVuibGXIbGXEZ6RhARAA)

This uses the formula `((b - a) * c) % (b - a)`, where a is the minimum of the range, b is the maximum of the range, and c is the wind. I noticed after posting this that the formula doesn't really work though.

```
-DZs*$ # stack is min, max, wind
-      # subtract
 D     # duplicate
  Zs   # swap bottom two
    *  # multiply
     $ # swapped modulus
```

Comment: It's not going to be different for any values if a = 0, b = 1, e.g.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 Thanks, not sure what I can change this to

Comment: You could, e.g. use a logistic function which is scaled to range between the given values?

Comment: Value -100 produce output out of range.
This general problem, it's not possible to do rescale without information about min and max of input

Comment: @lesobrod I'm working on a new way that will work better

Comment: @Jacob  TS clarified the question in the last comment

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), 31 bytes

```r
\(w,a,b)(.5+atan(w)/pi)*(b-a)+a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhb7YzTKdRJ1kjQ19Ey1E0sS8zTKNfULMjW1NJJ0EzW1EyGqbqalaRjoGeok2hoa6CTZGhlocqVpGBoZm5jqmZlbWBqgSujilvHMS0MVQRWA2LZgAYQGAA) or [Try it at rdrr.io with graphical output](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(w%2Ca%2Cb)(.5%2Batan(w)%2Fpi)*(b-a)%2Ba%0A%0Ax%3Dseq(-25%2C25%2Cby%3D.1)%0Aplot(x%2Cf(w%3Dx%2Ca%3D10%2Cb%3D20))%0A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 14 bytes

```
Ť←←Đ3Ș⇹-⇹↔⁺₂*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//6JJHbROA6MgE4xMzHrXv1AXiR21THjXuetTUpKX9/78BlwmXMQA)

Takes inputs as `c b a` (each on their own line)

Uses `tanh` as the mapping function

```
Ť                       implicit input (c); Ťanh(c)
 ←←                     get input twice (b, then a)
   Đ                    Đuplicate a
    3Ș                  Șwap top three items of stack
      ⇹                 swap top two on stack
       -                subtract (b-a)
        ⇹               swap top two on stack
         ↔              flip the stack
          ⁺             increment [tanh(c)+1]
           ₂            halve [(tanh(c)+1)/2]
            *           multiply [(b-a)*(tanh(c)+1)/2]
             +          add [a+(b-a)*(tanh(c)+1)/2]; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
ＮθＩ⁺θ∕⁻Ｎθ⊕Ｘ²Ｎ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/98zr6C0xK80Nym1SKNQ05oroCgzr0TDObG4RCMgp7RYo1BHwSWzLDMlVcM3Mw/IR1avqaNQCMSeeclFqbmpeSWpKRoB@eVACSOQIJI6CLD@/1/XWMHQQMHgv25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Another port of @adam's Python answer.

```
Ｎθ              First input as a number
       Ｎ        Second input as a number
      ⁻         Minus
        θ       First input
     ∕          Divided by
           ²    Literal integer `2`
          Ｘ     Raised to power
            Ｎ   Third input as a number
         ⊕      Incremented
   ⁺            Plus
    θ           First input
  Ｉ             Cast to string
                Implicitly print
```

Originally this was meant to be based on @KiptheMalamute's answer, so I started with:

$$ f(c) = a + \frac {2(b - a)} {1 + \tanh c} $$

Charcoal doesn't have hyperbolic (or indeed trigonometric) functions, so I rewrote this in terms of the exponential function:

$$ f(c) = a + \frac {b - a} {1 + e ^ {-2 c}} $$

But there's no particular reason to use \$ e^{-2} \$; any base will do, such as \$ 2 \$, which is much golfier:

$$ f(c) = a + \frac {b - a} {1 + 2 ^ c} $$