# Mapping Passing Through Point

Tags: code-golf, open-ended-function

(Inspired by [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258870/generate-number-from-given-range).)

Given six real values in three pairs: \$(x_1, x_2), (y_1, y_2),\$ and \$(x_0, y_0)\$, where  \$x_1 < x_0 < x_2\$ and \$y_1 < y_0 < y_2\$, create a function which maps between \$(x_1, x_2)\$ and \$(y_1, y_2)\$ which also passes through \$(x_0,y_0)\$. In other words, make some function

$$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},\; f((x_1, x_2)) = (y_1, y_2),\; f(x_0) = y_0$$

Note that the image of the function has to be over the whole interval -- in other words, for every \$y \in (y_1,y_2)\$, there must be some \$x \in (x_1,x_2)\$, such that \$f(x)=y\$.

- *The function does not need to be bijective.*
- The value of the function cannot be outside of the given \$y\$ range.

For example, for \$(x_1, x_2) = (0, 10), (y_1, y_2) = (0, 10), x_0 = 4, y_0 = 2\$, a possible function is

$$\begin{cases}
\frac12 x & 0 < x \leq 4 \\
-\frac43 x + \frac{46}{3} & 4 < x < 10
\end{cases}$$

[Which looks like](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fuymkx8lrd):

[image: graph of function meeting description above]

On the edge points (i.e. when \$x = x_1\$ or \$x = x_2\$) or outside of the interval, the function can have whatever value you want, or it can be undefined.

---

*Note: You don't have to return a function -- you could also write your code so that it takes in \$x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2, x_0, y_0, x\$ and returns \$y = f(x)\$ following the constraints above.*

Standard loopholes are forbidden. Since this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest function wins.

Comment: Is the second line in your example flipped? You say 10 should map to 10, and it would make more sense for 4+Δx to map to 2+Δy.

Comment: Is the image of \$f\$ required to be contained within \$(y_1,y_2)\$ over the interval \$x\in(x_1,x_2)\$, or can there be some value within the domain that maps to a value outside of \$(y_1,y_2)\$?

Comment: @AndersKaseorg It does not need to be bijective.

Comment: @Neil I don't think I understand your question.

Comment: @KiptheMalamute Yes, all values in the domain must produce an output within the range.

Comment: I didn't understand your formulae - what you're trying to say is that the function needs to map the open interval `(x₁, x₂)` to the open interval `(y₁, y₂)` and specifically the value `x₀` needs to map to `y₀`. The confusion arises because `(x₀, y₀)` is a coordinate but the others are open intervals.

Comment: For the mapping from the open interval `(0, 10)` to the open interval `(0, 10)` case, does that mean that it would be wrong for e.g. `2` to map to `0`, since that's not actually in the open interval?

Comment: @Neil ... I hadn't considered it; I suppose it would be forbidden by the rules I have laid out here.

Comment: In that case, Arnauld's answer, TheThonnu's port, DominicvanEssen's alternative answer and KiptheMalamute's answer all appear to at least technically infringe that clause in some way.

Comment: I suppose I should change it then... not sure how I should clarify that

Answer (score 9):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 6 bytes

```r
approx
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/saCgKL/if4VtsoaBjqGBJlclnFVhYGvCVWlga8TFlaaRrFGhU2GgqZOsUalTCaRNNf8DAA) or [Try it with graphical output at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3Dapprox%0A%0Ax%3Dc(0%2C10)%0Ay%3Dc(0%2C10)%0Ax0%3D4%0Ay0%3D2%0A%0Ax_toplot%3D0%3A100%2F10%0Aplot(f(c(x%2Cx0)%2Cc(y%2Cy0)%2Cx_toplot)))

Input is `x1,x2,x0`, `y1,y2,y0`, `x`; output is `x,y`.

This seems like a fairly straightforward task for which built-in solution ought to exist in [R](https://www.r-project.org/), and indeed it does.

---

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>48</s> 38 bytes

```r
\(a,b,c,x)(a+(x*(b+c-2*a)/c[1])%%b)[2]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGiNNulpSVpuhY31WI0EnWSdJJ1KjQ1ErU1KrQ0krSTdY20EjX1k6MNYzVVVZM0o41ioapTlRUSFTKLFSoMdSoNuZQVksAcI51KIyAnGcwx0Kk04Eq0TdYw0DHQ5EoCMgwNdAyBzGQg00THSJOLKw1qJVAQxjRBMM00IZYtWAChAQ) or [Try it with graphical output at rdrr.io](https://rdrr.io/snippets/embed/?code=f%3D%0Afunction(a%2Cb%2Cc%2Cx)(a%2B(x*(b%2Bc-2*a)%2Fc%5B1%5D)%25%25b)%5B2%5D%0A%0A%23%20a%20is%20x1%2Cy1%0A%23%20b%20is%20x2%2Cy2%0A%23%20c%20is%20x0%2Cy0%0Aa%3Dc(0%2C0)%0Ab%3Dc(10%2C10)%0Ac%3Dc(4%2C2)%0A%0Ax_toplot%3D0%3A100%2F10%0Aplot(x_toplot%2Csapply(x_toplot%2Cf%2Ca%3Da%2Cb%3Db%2Cc%3Dc))%0A)

Input is `x1,y1`, `x2,y2`, `x0,y0`, `x`; output is `y`.

Non-builtin solution.  Avoids any kind of curve-fitting tomfoolery by using a deliberately non-bijective function.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
&1Yn
```

The implemented mapping consists of two straight segments: the first from the point \$(x_1,y_1)\$ to \$(x_0,y_0)\$, and the second from \$(x_0,y_0)\$ to \$(x_2,y_2)\$.

The code inputs two numerical vectors and a number: `[x1 x0 x2]`, `[y1 y0 y2]`, `x`. Then it simply calls the `interp1` function, which linearly interpolates the data defined by `[x1 x0 x2]` and `[y1 y0 y2]` at the abscissa `x`. The ouput is the value `y` corresponding to `x`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X80wMu///2gDBRMFQ4NYLiDDCMwwBAA) You can also see the graph of the mapping [**here**](https://matl.io/?code=%26XG&inputs=%5B0+4+10%5D%0A%5B0+2+10%5D&version=22.7.4).

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 71 bytes

Expects \$(x_0,x_1,x_2,y_0,y_1,y_2,x)\$.

Just uses quadratic interpolation, which is most certainly not the shortest approach.

```javascript
(a,b,c,d,e,f,x)=>(x-b)*((f-e)/(c-b)-(e-=d)/(b-=a))/(c-a)*(x-=a)+e/b*x+d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYzLDoIwEEX3fMUspzAVS9iR@iOGRZ9GQ6gRYsrX18G4dMHiJvdxch/mbRb3uj9XOScfStQFDVly5ClQpCz0BbO0okaMMogWHQeJQWrPwUptxLc0TOQ9NaG1dW58mcIKV8hngqxYHcHGfmO/dTCC5rEn4Eqxup8bh6pyaV7SFE5TumHE/weMCzEcRPvjqNpvywc)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 31 bytes

```
ＮθＮηＮζＦ⊕›θη«ＮεＮδ»Ｉ⁺ζ∕×⁻θη⁻δζ⁻εη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BCsIwDEDP9ityTKCCiuBhRwXZQdnBH6hrZIWt067dYeK3186BTEku78FLykq5slV1jLm9B38OzZUdPigTc67@eEh8ax1gbkvHDVvPGo@OlR9jCRURwVMs5g2n5kfoJF6icMZ63KvOY1GHDgcJB9MbzXgxDXd4MjbZz00JE2gJA32Jp3dEWYw72MIGVmnW48ZlX78B) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as seven numbers `x`, `x₀`, `y₀`, `x₁`, `y₁`, `x₂` and `y₂`. Explanation: Performs linear interpolation between `x₀` and `y₀` and either `x₁` and `y₁` or `x₂` and `y₂` depending on whether `x` is greater than `x₀` or not.

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `x`.

```
ＮηＮζ
```

Input `x₀` and `y₀`.

```
Ｆ⊕›θη«ＮεＮδ»
```

Input `x₁` and `y₁` or `x₂` and `y₂` depending on whether `x` is greater than `x₀`.

```
Ｉ⁺ζ∕×⁻θη⁻δζ⁻εη
```

Perform linear interpolation.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 33 bytes

```
Đ←=?ĉ←:←ŕŕ←←-Đ↔⇹ᵮ₄%⇹/4*←Đ←⇹-⇹↔*+;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yIRHbRNs7Y90AikrID469ehUIAVEuiCpKY/adz7cuu5RU4sqkKVvogWUAGsB8nSBGKhCS9v6/39DPRMuQz1TLmMuEy4DIDQBAA)

Uses \$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ c l }y_0 &\quad\textrm{if }x=x_0 \\y_1+(y_2-y_1)*{4\left(x\!\!\!\!\mod\!{x_2-x_1\over 4}\right)\over x_2-x_1}& \quad\textrm{otherwise}\end{array}\right. \$

Takes input as the following, each on a new line: `x x0 y0 x2 x1 y1 y2`

| Code | Stack | Action |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Đ | \$x\ x\$ | implicit input; `Đ`uplicate |
| ← | \$x\ x\ x_0\$ | get \$x_0\$ |
| =? | \$x\ \{x\!=\!x_0\}\$ | if \$x=x_0\$: |
| ĉ← | \$y_0\$ | `ĉ`lear the stack and get \$y_0\$ |
| :←ŕŕ | \$x\$ | otherwise, get \$y_0\$ and then `ŕ`emove \$\{x\!=\!x_0\}\$ and \$y_0\$ |
| ←←- | \$x\ z\$ | get \$x_2\$ and \$x_1\$ and then subtract (call it \$z\$) |
| Đ | \$x\ z\ z\$ | `Đ`uplicate |
| ↔⇹ | \$z\ x\ z\$ | manipulate the stack |
| ᵮ₄ | \$z\ x\ {z\over4}\$ | cast to `ᵮ`loat, then divide by 4 |
| % | \$z\ q\$ | \$x\!\!\!\!\mod\!\! {z\over4}\$ (call it \$q\$) |
| ⇹ | \$q\ z\$ | swap top two items on stack |
| / | \${q\over z}\$ | divide |
| 4* | \${4q\over z}\$ | multiply by 4 |
| ←Đ | \${4q\over z}\ y_1\ y_1\$ | get \$y_1\$ and `Đ`uplicate |
| ← | \${4q\over z}\ y_1\ y_1\ y_2\$ | get \$y_2\$ |
| ⇹- | \${4q\over z}\ y_1\ m\$ | swap top two on stack and then subtract (call it \$m\$) |
| ⇹↔ | \$y_1\ m\ {4q\over z}\$ | manipulate the stack |
| * | \$y_1\ {4mq\over z}\$ | multiply |
| + | \$y_1+{4mq\over z}\$ | add |
| ; |  | either way, implicit print |

The function is onto \$(y_1,y_2)\$ as follows:

It can be trivially shown that if the discontinuity at \$x_0\$ did not exist, then \$\forall y\in(y_1,y_2)\$, \$\exists\$ at least one \$x\in(x_1,x_2)\$ s.t. \$f(x)=y\$. In fact, there would be between two and four such points for all values.

Some of you may object here and say that \$\nexists x\in(x_1,x_2)\$ s.t. \$f(x)=y_2\$, and you'd be right. However, the problem lists the intervals as open, and so the endpoints are not necessary.

Since without the discontinuity, there would be at least two distinct \$x\in(x_1,x_2)\$ such that \$f(x)=y\$, with the discontinuity, every point must have at least one such \$x\$. Therefore, \$f(x)\$ is onto \$(y_1,y_2)\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 81 bytes

```python
lambda a,b,c,d,e,f,x:(x-b)*((f-e)/(c-b)-(e:=e-d)/(b:=b-a))/(c-a)*(x:=x-a)+e/b*x+d
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XUw9CsIwGN09xTd-Sb_QVjpIIDdwcVaHpElQiLVIhHgWl4DonbyNwXbR4fF-effXeIuH85AfXu2e1-jF6r0J-mSsBk2GerLkyFOSmIRhHNELx2rsixHopHLCFmukMkKzb6HLKkmViqhcbXiq7Hy8DqBgCx1BQ9AWLGe1X4yX4xDRIw8E0DD2G3R_QVsW02fOE38A)

Port of Arnauld's JS answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 55 bytes

```javascript
f=(p,a,b,x,y,c,d)=>p>x?f(p,x,y,c,d):(y-b)/(x-a)*(p-a)+b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYzBDoIwEETvfMUeW13UNpwkxQ8xHNoCRtPQBohpvx63Bi8ejMnOZjK78x76qWc73cNSjr7r10HRsIAaDUZMaLHjqglNvAyUfpIzS6XhRxZLzXcs0N6b1fULXCGeEKIgSYREPpFPElpQdKwQKBIkubm2Lgrrx9m7/uD8jQ1s6@deZmXGmyU5r79eq/9fxS/s@gI)

The linear map must be not shortest

Two segments